# Using wildcards with Doctrine's createQuery method

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this query isn't working please? I tried alternating between single and double quotes as well.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT t FROM AcmeBlogBundle:BlogTag t WHERE t.title LIKE \'%:title%\'')
->setParameter('title', $keyword);
```

Doctrine simply returns `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`.

Also, is it better to perform such a query using the createQuery method or createQueryBuilder?

Comment: I think you want to select all the table, for that you have to use SELECT * ... and not SELECT t. Was that it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[PDO treats both the keyword and the % wildcards as a single token. You cannot add the wildcards next to the placeholder. You must append them to the string when you bind the params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761976/1041885).

Also see [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#99698) on the php docs.

Therefore you will need to do the following:

```php
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb
    ->select('tag')
    ->from('AcmeBlogBundle:BlogTag', 'tag')
    ->where($qb->expr()->like('tag.title', ':title'))
    ->setParameter('title', '%' . $keyword . '%')
;
```

or

```php
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT t FROM AcmeBlogBundle:BlogTag t WHERE t.title LIKE :title');
$query->setParameter('title', '%' . $keyword . '%');
```

I prefer to use the query builder because it is nicer for structuring and making your statement more maintainable

Comment: What are chances of SQL injection by directly appending $keyword, I think there is, is there any other safer way to do it.