# SQLite Like % and _

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like

I can't figure out what the underscore character does in an SQLite `like` statement.
The wildcard character, `%`, is probably the same as in most other SQL databases.

So, what does the `_` character do?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The underscore is also the same as in most other SQL databases and matches any single character (i.e. it is the same as `.` in a regular expression). From the [fine manual](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

> An underscore ("_") in the LIKE pattern matches any single character in the string.

For example:

```
-- The '_' matches the single 'c'
sqlite> select 'pancakes' like 'pan_akes';
1
-- This would need '__' to match the 'ca', only one '_' fails.
sqlite> select 'pancakes' like 'pan_kes';
0
-- '___' also fails, one too many '_'.
sqlite> select 'pancakes' like 'pan___kes';
0
```

And just to make sure the results make sense: SQLite uses [zero and one for booleans](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean).

Answer (score 98):

It is standard SQL that in `LIKE` expressions:

- `%` matches any sequence of characters, including an empty one. It is equivalent to `.*` in a regular expression.
- `_` matches a single character. It is equivalent to `.` in a regular expression.
- You can choose a character for escaping `%`, `_` and itself itself with:

  ```
  ... WHERE expr LIKE 'a_b%c\\d\%\_' ESCAPE '\'
  ```

  This will match `a×b×××c\d%_` or `a×bc\d%_` but not `abc\d%_` nor `a×b×××cd%_`.

Additionnally with SQLite you have the `GLOB` keyword which behaves exactly the same way, except that `%` becomes `*` and `_` becomes `?`.

Comment: Thank you, Benoit. I chose the other answer judging by time only.

Comment: This saved my life. I was looking how to escape '%' in SQLite queries. But I had to give '\\' to get it working, not just '\' (I was working on Javscript+WebSQL). Below query worked for me. SELECT * FROM offers WHERE title LIKE '%50\\%%' ESCAPE '\\' (this will return all offers with title having 50%)

Comment: @Francisc, I think you were fair in the beginning to choose the answer according to the time, but this answer is more clear than the currently accepted answer. It would be a service to future users to make this the accepted answer.

Comment: SQLite's `GLOB` is not exactly the same as `LIKE` but with different symbols.  It's always case-sensitive, doesn't allow `ESCAPE`, and also supports character classes and ranges.

Answer (score 13):

Addendum to @Benoit's answer:

The `ESCAPE` applies to the most recent `LIKE` expression, not all `LIKE` expressions. To escape all you must use `ESCAPE` multiple times, such as below.

```
WHERE foo LIKE '%bar^%%' ESCAPE '^' AND foo LIKE '%baz^_%' ESCAPE '^'
```

This predicate matches values of `foo` which contain *bar%*, or *baz* plus any character.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I use in XCode/Objective-C environment, '\' doesn't work. Use anything else instead...

> C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)