# Doctrine2 "Like" SQL query and "Class true does not exist" error

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've see the major post on the Doctrine "LIKE" query topic (see, for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843009/how-to-escape-like-var-with-doctrine)). I have a SYmfony2 application. In a controller I call an entity repository to make a query. In particular, in the entity repository I define the following function:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("SELECT p FROM AcmePromoBundle:Promo p 
            JOIN p.product pr 
            WHERE pr.name LIKE 'La'")->getResult();
```

It works but doesn't return anything, because there is no Product (*pr*) such that its name is La.
Then, I try to add the **%** character inside the SQL query like follows here:

```
"SELECT p FROM AcmePromoBundle:Promo p JOIN p.product pr WHERE pr.name LIKE 'La%'"
```

and here:

```
"SELECT p FROM AcmePromoBundle:Promo p JOIN p.product pr WHERE pr.name LIKE La%"
```

but the following error is returned "**Class true does not exist**".
I also tried to use "**setParameter**" function but it doesn't work! Any idea?

Comment: Although I'm using a bit oldish release of 2.0 Doctrine, queries like that one worked with no problem. Maybe you should update your Doctrine to latest release?

Comment: Mhhh! I'm using the last Symfony2 release! I suppose that Doctrine is already updated!

Comment: True but you should check nevertheless. There might be a bug that was fixed in some of later releases ;)

Comment: Are you absolutely certain this query is the cause? I don't see anything anywhere which would show up in a string as 'true'. Have you checked your mappings are correct as well (iirc you can use validate-mappings in command line tool)? I've used join queries in many D2 versions and they always worked fine, I don't think LIKE should have an effect on it.

Comment: @JaniHartikainen No I'm not! In fact I posted the error that happens when I call this function. You drawn a possible cause... I'm going to investigate. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: @JaniHartikainen Well! I don't know what is happening. I check the entity classes, they seems to be ok! The error happens in `...\Acme\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php` at **line 194**. The code is `if (($paramClass = $param->getClass()) !== null)`. So it seems that the `getClass()` function of the `$param` variable return true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now It works! I only added the **__toString** function inside all the entity classes! E.g.:

```
public function __toString(){
    return '\Acme\PromoBundle\Entity\Promo';
}
```