# Doctrine 2 Query with LIKE

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this code for query:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('AcmeCrawlerBundle:Trainings');
       $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
               ->where('p.title LIKE :word')
               ->orWhere('p.discription LIKE :word')
               ->setParameter('word', $word)
               ->getQuery();
$trainings = $query->getResult();
```

The problem is: even if matches exist, they not found by this query. I used this code to see full sql:

```
print_r(array(
        'sql'        => $query->getSQL(),
        'parameters' => $query->getParameters(),
        ));
```

And what I've got:

```
FROM Trainings t0_ WHERE t0_.title LIKE ? OR t0_.discription LIKE ? [parameters] => Array ( [word] => Spoken )
```

(last part of query)
Tell me please what to change?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You forgot the `%` signs around the word:

```php
->setParameter('word', '%'.$word.'%')
```

Comment: why is doctrine doing this automatically when I pass a parameter to the like function ?

Comment: It's secure do it? By appending directly the string?

Comment: @baquiax it's secure because parameter is escaped while preparing statement.

Answer (score 35):

Below are some additional steps you can take to further sanitise input data.

You should escape the term that you insert between the percentage signs:

```
->setParameter('word', '%'.addcslashes($word, '%_').'%')
```

The percentage sign '%' and the symbol underscore '_' are interpreted as wildcards by `LIKE`. If they're not escaped properly, an attacker might construct arbitrarily complex queries that can cause a denial of service attack. Also, it might be possible for the attacker to get search results he is not supposed to get. A more detailed description of attack scenarios can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7893670/623685

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov You can improve your answer, then I'll delete mine.

Comment: See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/security.html 
Even the examples in doctrine documentation does NOT escape the values. Hmm why?

Comment: The way in which the accepted answer uses the query builder causes the generated SQL to leverage *prepared statements* which means that the answer is neither 'wrong' nor 'insecure'. I'd go as far as saying that _this_ answer is wrong.

Comment: Arguably, this answer is wrong. Especially when using this answer's definition of "wrong". You should avoid 'rolling your own' security - as this answer encourages. The accepted answer very properly uses Doctrine's built-in security mechanisms.

Comment: Come on, guys. Look at the stackoverflow post I've linked in my answer. In short: The setParameter magic protects against SQL injection, but not against wildcard injection. I would like to point out that I have actually tested this myself, and all of it is true. We're not making this up. Without escaping % and _ manually, they will be interpreted as wildcards. Again: setParameter protects against SQL injection, but not against this type of wildcard injection.

Comment: I can confirm, passing `%` into the like expression (between other `%` signs) still returns every record in the database in Doctrine 2.8.1. As for why Doctrine doesn't guard against this could be simply because there may be wild cards put there intentionally.