# Doctrine and Symfony2: WHERE a.title LIKE $array

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hey I'm writing this post because I have few problem passing an array value in the doctrine query.

Here is the entire query as it is:

```
$data = $request->request->all();
$dql   = "SELECT a FROM PfBlogBundle:Article a WHERE a.title LIKE '{$data['search']}' ORDER by a.id DESC";
```

If I print_r($data) I get the value so it's there somewhere. I just don't understand why it's not passing in the query.. Was expecting LIKE '{$data['search']}' to work but it doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 Query with LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706337/doctrine-2-query-with-like)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From what I can tell by your snippet, you're looking for something like this:

```
$entityManager->getRepository('PfBlogBundle:Article')
              ->findBy(
                   array(
                      'key' => 'value'
                   )
               );
```

Where key is the property/field and the value is the value to look for. Check the Symfony manual page. The bit you're after is [Fetching Objects from the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).
To use a `like` in the where clause, [refer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706337/doctrine-2-query-with-like), on how to use `setParameter`. You'll get your query with this:

```
$repo = $entityManager->getRepository('PfBlogBundle:Article');
$query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('a')
               ->where('a.title LIKE :title')
               ->setParameter('title', '%'.$data['search'].'%')
               ->getQuery();
```

Of course, add wildcards to suite your needs. I've enclosed the `$data['search']` value in two `%` wildcards, which is slow, but then again: I don't know what you're actually doing. It might be that all you're after is the case-insensitive nature of `LIKE`, in which case the `%` can be left out all together...

Based on your previous questions (BTW: consider accepting an answer once in a while):

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->get->all();
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()
                  ->getRepository('PfBlogBundle:Article');
    $query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('a')
                   ->where('a.title LIKE :title')
                   ->setParameter('title', '%'.$data['search'].'%')
                   ->getQuery();
    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query->getResults(),//get the results here
        $this->requrest->get('page',1),
        4
    );
    return $this->render('PfBlogBundle:Default:blog.html.twig', array('pagination'=>$pagination));
}
```

But this is just a crude fix, [Google doctrine-symfony pagination](http://tecnofuenteabierta.blogspot.be/2011/03/using-pagination-with-symfony-and.html), there are many detailed blog-posts on the matter

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still learning it and the less I can say, it's not an easy task!Hope I'll get it! Thanks again, I will try doing things this way then...

Comment: @user1880789: Glad to see you appreciate my efforts. Don't take this the wrong way, but [the SO way of saying thanks is not by commenting, but by accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answers. In fact, [you're asked _not_ to comment with _"thanks"_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), check bottom of help-page